# How can I stop whole application after a car arrives at destiny

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

The title is pretty self explanatory. I need to kill the whole simulation after a car arrives at his destiny, disregarding everything that happens next. How can I achieve such goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `endSimulation()` method, to terminate the simulation programmatically. You should place this call where the positions are evaluated and you can check whether the arrival condition is true.